# I'm looking for a Sharepoint Webpart that can query a list for an RSS feed URL, then display it

Tags: sharepoint, rss, web-parts

Basically what I have a List that will be maintained by the user that has a field that contains a link to an RSS feed.

I tried using the OOTB RSS and it's great, but you have to specify the feed URL and I need that to be based on user selection. For example, the user will select from a list a feed they want to view and this should take them to the feed reader page which will use their selection to get the feed URL and display this on the page.

Comment: This could be done with our product [MatchPoint](http://www.colygon.com). MatchPoint is an application framework for SharePoint. One of the features is the [connection framework](http://www.colygon.com/technical-features/service-layer-and-api/connection-framework) which simplifies and improves web part connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative which is not a general Sharepoint solution is to use jquery.

Is the list visible on the page or is it "just" a list in Sharepoint?

Of course you might need some kind of proxy to do this in order to call the rss-feeds if they are placed on another server. But you will send the performance to the client instead of the server which is a plus..

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use the WebPartPages Web Service (SaveWebPart) to change the definition of the web part to use the new feed URL whenever a feed is clicked on.

I created a javascript function the will accept the feed URL and proceed to the page where the feed is displayed. The new feed will not be loaded until the next time you visit the page, therefore if you are already on it you will need to reload, thus the redirect.

For more information on the format of the request and the web part XML format see the following page.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms774839%28v=office.12%29.aspx

```
function SetFeed(feedURL){

var webPartGUID = $("#<WebPartID>").attr('webpartid');  

    // This is where you set the page URL, Full Web Part XML (including path to FEED), 
    // storageKey (webPart GUID), and storage type (none, personal, shared)
var soapEnv = "<FULL SOAP XML>";


jQuery.ajax({
    url: "http://<SITE PATH>/_vti_bin/WebPartPages.asmx",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "xml",
    data: soapEnv,
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction",
        "http://microsoft.com/sharepoint/webpartpages/SaveWebPart")
    },
    complete: function(xData, status){
        window.location='REDIRECT TO FEED PAGE';
    },
    contentType: "text/xml;charset='utf-8'"
  });
}
```